# Replace/Add several DOM Elements: Efficient and robust Method?

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, performance

I am in search for an efficient method to replace a couple of DOM Elements - if possible in one action only.
It is needed for augmenting TextNodes. If a certain word is present, it shall be wrapped in span-Tags, to which an event handler needs to be assigned later.

so if a text Node contains the word it needs to turn from

```
-#textNode
```

to

```
- #textNode
- span
  - #textNode
- #textNode
```

While leaving the rest of the document untouched.

Known/assumed issues:
- innerHTML would be fast, but the Elements would need to have a generated ID and be later retrieved later again via getElementByID; not the cleanest/fastest way.
- Cloning the node, putting it into an documentFragment, doing all operations and replacing it back again would be good – but cloning does discard event handlers as far as I know. Since this code is to be used in an Bookmarklet/Add-On this is not an option than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DOM Level 1 Core method [`splitText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-splitText) on the Text node, once on the point just after the target text then once just before. `createElement` a new `span`, `replaceChild` the middle Text node (containing the target text) and `appendChild` that Text node into the span. Add event handlers etc. to the span as necessary.

No need to start messing with `innerHTML` or clever Range/adjacentHTML hacks; you're not really going to get any faster than this. Don't believe the hype: DOM manipulations like `splitText` or a single insertion aren't slow at all. It's only when you try to manipulate a lot of contiguous nodes all at once that other methods can improve matters.